# PHP script won't sent mail

Tags: php, mysql, database, email

I wrote a script that's suppose to send and an email upon new subscription but the mail function doesn't send it. It is getting the email from the database and adding it to the from field which I found out doesn't send, but if I just type in an email it works.

**Mail script:**

```
function curPageURL() {
             $pageURL = 'http';
             if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
             $pageURL .= "://";
             if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
              $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
             } else {
              $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
             }
             return $pageURL;
        }

        $a = curPageURL();

        $b =  explode('/',$a);

        $value = $b['3'];

        // Get date from MySQL Server
        $currentdate = mysql_query('select CURDATE()');
        $curdate = mysql_result($currentdate,0);

        $dayone = 1;

        // Insert the new user to the database since everything is fine
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO optionusers (userid, name, email, join_date, day_one) 
        VALUES 
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('ssssi', $value, $name, $email, $curdate, $dayone);

        $stmt->execute();
        $inserted_id = $mysqli->insert_id;
        $stmt->close();


        global $mysqli; 

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM optionusers WHERE userid = '$value' AND join_date ='$curdate' AND day_one ='$dayone'";
        $optinuseremails = $mysqli->query($sql);
        while($row = $optinuseremails->fetch_object()){
            $optinemails .= $row->email. ", ";
            echo $optinemails;

            //Select email address from userdata table
            $stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE userid = '$value'");
            $reffer  = $stmt->fetch_object();
            $stmt->close();

            $refferinfo = $reffer->email_address;

            echo $refferinfo;


            //Select email template
            $stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM email_templates WHERE serial = '1'");
            $result = $stmt->fetch_object();
            $stmt->close();

            $template1 = $result->serial;
            $template_subject = $result->subject;
            $template_text = $result->message;

            eval("\$body=\"$template_text\";");

            $header = "Content-type:text/html \r\n";
            $header .= "From: ".$refferinfo." \r\n";


            if(!mail($optinemails,$template_subject,$body,$header)){
                echo "could not send mail";
            }else{
                mail($optinemails,$template_subject,$body,$header);
            }

            $from = $refferinfo; // sender
            $subject = "It is 3 days";
            // message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
            $message = "It is now 3 days the script works";
            // send mail
            mail("carltondavis19@gmail.com",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");
        }
        //Update day value if user already got emailed
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE optionusers SET day_one = 1 WHERE userid = '$value' AND day_one = '0'");
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
```

Comment: is there extra white space from the db or slashes or any weird characters?

Comment: No none at all, if i remove this section: //Select email address from userdata table of the code and just put in a email it sends. But as soon as i uncomment that section it stops working.

Comment: what's the echo telling you? there is something slightly wrong, you're just not seeing,

Comment: i am just echoing this echo $optinemails; and this echo $refferinfo; to see the emails, everything looks ok but no mail.

Comment: also i am using fatcow hosting